# Elastic Search Index Status

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup a scripted reindex operation as suggested in: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/

To go with the suggestion of creating a new index, aliasing then deleting the old index I would need to have a way to tell when the indexing operation on the new index was complete. Ideally via the REST interface.

It has 80 million rows to index and can take a few hours.

I can't find anything helpful in the docs..

Comment: How are you constructing the new index? You can swap the alias over after the last document is inserted into the new index. Granted, there may be some time for documents to be replicated across the cluster.

Comment: I am using a river via a JDBC connection. I need to know when the river operation has completed.                          curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_index/_meta' -d '{
         "type" : "jdbc",
         "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
         "url" : "jdbc:mysql://",
         "user" : "",
         "password" : "",
         "sql" : "select * from test",
         "index" : "blah",
         "type" : "poi"
 }
}'

Comment: OK. It may be useful to edit your question to add those details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with _stats : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html

Eg :

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "docs" : {
        "count" : 0,
        "deleted" : 0
      },
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 575,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
      },
      "indexing" : {
        "index_total" : 0,
        "index_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "index_current" : 0,
        "delete_total" : 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "delete_current" : 0,
        "noop_update_total" : 0,
        "is_throttled" : false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
      },
```

I think, you can compare _all.total.docs.count and _all.total.indexing.index_current